# How do I disable the Super key?

Tags: shortcut-keys

I want to disable the <kbd>Super</kbd> key, when I press <kbd>Super</kbd> nothing should happen.

How can I do that?

Comment: The "Super" key (a.k.a. "Windows" key) acts like a meta key such as Ctrl and Alt. In Unity, it's supposed to open the Launcher. To open the applications menu, use Alt + F1. I've no idea how to disable it though.

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/a/1039164/587882 to disable the super key for the launcher.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

You can change that in Compiz.

1. Install `compizconfig-settings-manager`

   ```
   sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager
   ```
2. Hit <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>, type `about:config` and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> to open the Unity configuration.

   Or run `ccsm` on the command line.
3. Change or disable the shortcut for *Key to show the launcher* as you like to free your <kbd>Super</kbd> key:

   [image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: The tab layout is different now (in 13.04), but you click around you can still find the Launcher setting, and it still works.  This is a blessing for Emacs users.

Comment: This does not work anymore. I have no idea why but it appears like there is no way to disable the "Super" key showing the "search bar" in Ubuntu anymore (if there ever was a way). I've tried literally everything.

Comment: @Mike, it works for me (Ubuntu 15.04), it's like user100464 said, it's just in a different location

Comment: Works for me Ubuntu 15.10. The new location is "Ubuntu Unity Plugin > Launcher"

Comment: I disabled "Key to show the launcher", but now a new search felt pops up "type your command" when I press the super key. Ubuntu 17.04

Comment: @Peheje you an use compizconfig-settings-manager to search and disable or change yours keyboard shortcuts.

Comment: "Hit Alt+F2, type about:config and hit Enter" : That results in "Command not found" (18.04).

Comment: In 18.04 ccsm's advanced search does not find anything for "launcher".

Comment: @NicolasRaoul As noted above, this works for the latest install on ubuntu 16.04: 
 in the filter box, type: "ubuntu unity plugin", and then you'll be in the "unity" meny.  Then click the launcher tab.  Or if you want more visual steps:   https://www.faqforge.com/linux/make-super-key-launch-custom-program-rather-unity-search-ubuntu/

Answer (score 21):

Execute the following command and then log in Unity desktop environment again.

```
dconf write /org/compiz/profiles/unity/plugins/unityshell/show-launcher '""'
```

In Ubuntu 12.04 and later:

```
gconftool-2 --set "/apps/compiz-1/plugins/unityshell/screen0/options/show_launcher" --type string ""
```

Comment: This is great for those of us who don't want to have to install compiz-settings-manager!

Comment: Has the way keyboard shortcuts work changed between Ubuntu 12.04 and 14.04?

Comment: On Ubuntu 14.04 (Trusty), I used `gsettings set org.compiz.integrated show-hud "['']"`.

Comment: The `dconf write ...` worked for me in 16.04.

Comment: @mmoya checked on Ubuntu 16.10 - didn't work: `dconf write..`

Comment: `gconftool-2 ...` has no effect in 18.04 it seems.

Comment: Is there a way to revert this?

Answer (score 20):

In Ubuntu 20.04, running this command works for me:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.mutter overlay-key ''
```

From https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2405352

Comment: This is the only answer here that worked for me on Ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: Use dconf-editor if you prefer a graphical tool to change the setting. I installed dconf-editor and changed org.gnome.mutter overlay-key from Super_L to Super_R and that solved my problems!

Comment: This was painless for me in 21.10 impish. Thanks a ton brianpeiris!

Comment: Anyone happens to know the equivalent for `Lubuntu` ?

Answer (score 11):

Just putting the following lines into your **~/.Xmodmap** and then log out and log in Unity again.

```
keycode 133 = NoSymbol
keycode 134 = NoSymbol
```

Comment: I suspect that would prevent the user from assigning that key to any other function.

Comment: Which is just what I needed.  I actually add NoSymbol multiple times on each line in order to suppress its use with other modifier keys.  Thanks!

Comment: Perfect. I was really struggling to find these keycodes.

Answer (score 0):

As @user.dz has mentioned [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/850202/1667174), you can install `gnome-tweaks` either from Ubuntu Software or via [apt](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-install-and-use-gnome-tweak-tool-on-ubuntu/).

Then, going through Keyboard & Mouse, under Keyboard, you can set Overview Shortcut to Right Super.

It happened to work for me since I almost always use the left Command key on my Mac.