# How do I disable the long press Super key from showing the shortcuts window?

Tags: compiz, shortcut-keys, zooming

Note this is the **long press** and not the one for the short press as mentioned here [How do I disable the Super key?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/105558/how-do-i-disable-the-super-key)

The super key has been a modifier long before Unity came, and I have used it on **Compiz Zoom** feature. So holding super down and moving the mouse scroll would zoom in and out the screen. But now in 12.04 the shortcut list screen pops up and it is irritating. I have also tried changing the keys to control +super + mouse scroll and a similar thing happens.

Is there anyway to disable or change the long press super key for this, I have searched Compiz Unity plugin, the Systems Preferences - Keyboard shortcuts settings and haven't been able to find this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1) Install [Compiz-Settings-Manager](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/compizconfig-settings-manager) (`sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager`),

2) Go to "Ubuntu Unity Plugin" > "Experimental" and uncheck "Enable Shortcuts Hint Overlay".

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If I'm not mistaken (too bad I'm not in Ubuntu right now to check it out), you can also use [Unity Tweak Tool](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/unity-tweak-tool/) to disable the shortcuts overlay.

Answer (score 0):

For those who do not wish to install Compiz-Settings-Manager and/or prefer to use scripts to configure Ubuntu, this setting is stored in gconf and can be edited with gconftool-2.

This works in Ubuntu 12.04:

```
gconftool-2 --set "/apps/compiz-1/plugins/unityshell/screen0/options/shortcut_overlay" --type boolean false
```

To check your work and see other key-value pairs you can configure:

```
gconftool-2 --recursive-list "/apps/compiz-1/plugins/unityshell/screen0/options"
```

Comment: Can you use gsettings under Ubuntu 12.04?