# How to disable One[Single]  key shortcuts in Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, shortcut-keys

I do not like one key shortcuts. Whenever I press this while writing, one key triggers unneeded software. Thus, I have some problems :

- How can I close Alt shortcuts? ( pressing Alt triggers to type your command )
- How can I close SuperKey shortcuts ?
- How can I close Ctrl shortcuts ?

Comment: Have you tried disabling the shortcuts by custom selection via **System Settings >> Keyboard >> Shortcuts tab**. You simply have to select the unwanted shortcut by editing and Pressing Backspace key to Disable it.

Comment: Yes. Please, before commenting something, try by yourself.

Comment: At least in a clean 14.04 (Trusty) installation, the Alt key alone does NOT appear as a trigger in the Shortcuts tab - indeed, you can't have modifier-only triggers at all in Shortcuts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Download and Install [compizconfig-settings-manager [image: Install compizconfig-settings-manager]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/compizconfig-settings-manager).

> **Warning:** Compiz config settings manager is an advanced tool and improper use may break your unity interface. It is always a good idea to write down all the changes you make, so that in case something evil happens, it is easy to revert.

Launch the program and in the Desktop section you will find "Ubuntu Unity Plugin". From here you can edit the unity shortcuts under the Behavior/Switcher tabs.

Comment: @ gcc - For more info about how to in Compiz Config Settings Manager, you can refer this [answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/144327/63025)

Comment: How can I disable Ctrl shortcut ?