# How do I prevent the “Super” button from opening Activities?

Tags: shortcut-keys, gnome-shell, activities-overview

Combinations with the <kbd>Super</kbd> button are used by my IME.

Whenever I am a bit too slow, the default behavior of <kbd>Super</kbd> kicks in and the "Activities" screen appear, showing all of my current windows. It is very annoying.

**Question: How to disable the "Super" shortcut?**

Notes:

- I am not using Unity.
- [Unity-centric question with Unity-centric answers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/144325/how-do-i-disable-the-long-press-super-key-from-showing-the-shortcuts-window)

Comment: 19.04 ... I guess I should wait a few hours before asking?

Comment: as a workaround.. can you change the thing from left super to right super.. if you dont use right super for your regular work? https://i.stack.imgur.com/6rnfF.png

Comment: Thanks! (^_^;) The combinations work fine, in particular Super+Space. I just want to disable the "Super" only shortcut.

Comment: Super+Space is the standard for switching IMEs, my body is used to it and I guess all Japanese/etc users are also used to it, after using it every few seconds for years.

Comment: 19.04 questions are acceptable so close to the release. Bugs are always closed regardless of release.

Comment: Did you try changing the overview shortcut *from* left-Super *to* right-Super using GNOME Tweaks as @PRATAP suggested? That should solve your problem "if you dont use right super for your regular work" or if your keyboard doesn't even have a right-Super key *without* breaking Super+Space or any other combo.