# How can I disable Super Key in ubuntu-mate 18.04?

Tags: 18.04, mate

In Mate 18.04 the super key opens the application Menu. I would like to disable this keybinding but I cannot find it neither in the keyboard shortcuts menu nor with dconf editor.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

On my clean installation of Ubuntu MATE 18.04 LTS the following commands
disabled left <kbd>Super</kbd> / <kbd>Win</kbd> key:

```
gsettings set org.mate.mate-menu hot-key ''
gsettings set com.solus-project.brisk-menu hot-key ''
```

If you want to get it back - the default value for both keys was `'Super_L'`.