# How to set up i3wm with a desktop environment?

Tags: sound, multiple-monitors, desktop-environments, i3-wm

I really enjoy the i3 windows manager (https://i3wm.org/) as it takes out the pain of managing window locations manually.

However as i3 is only a window manager but not a desktop environment, it lacks some functions such as easy support for connecting a second display or changing the sound volume.

How can I set up i3 with a decent desktop environment, so get the best of both worlds?

Answer (score 0):

I've set up i3 with the MATE desktop, they play together nicely.

Steps to set it up:

1. I started from a ubuntu server installation
2. Install MATE Desktop environment: `sudo apt install ubuntu-mate-desktop dconf-editor` and reboot (you should now be able to log into ubuntu MATE)
3. Open `dconf-editor`:

   - `org > mate > desktop > session > required-components`. Change `windowmanager` from `marco` to `i3`.
   - `org > mate > desktop > session` and in `required-component-list`, delete `filemanager`.
   - `org > mate > mate-menu`, remove `hot-key`
   - `com > solus-project > brisk-menu`, remove `hot-key`
   - Install https://github.com/city41/mate-i3-applet for a nice workspace indicator

Use the following color scheme to match with the MATE colors (in `~/.config/i3/config`):

```
bar {
    tray_output None
    mode invisible
    colors {
        background #000000
        statusline #ffffff
        separator #666666

        focused_workspace  #4c7899 #285577 #ffffff
        active_workspace   #333333 #5f676a #ffffff
        inactive_workspace #333333 #222222 #888888
        urgent_workspace   #2f343a #900000 #ffffff
        binding_mode       #2f343a #900000 #ffffff
    }
}
```

Sources:

- https://www.mattgreer.org/articles/mate-and-i3/
- https://askubuntu.com/a/1039164

Answer (score 0):

Open your terminal and write to it:

1. Install i3:
   `sudo apt install i3`
2. Change your window manager to i3:
   `dconf write /org/mate/desktop/session/required-components/windowmanager "'i3'"`
3. Hide desktop with icons that covers our windows:
   `dconf write /org/mate/desktop/background/show-desktop-icons false`
4. Log out and go back

You can use this tutorial: https://ubuntu-mate.community/t/how-to-install-i3wm-mate