# How to disable windows key, to not pop out the Advanced MATE Menu?

Tags: keyboard, mate, menu, panel

I use MATE Desktop on Ubuntu 20.04.

Advanced MATE Menu is at the left corner of the top panel.
Compared to the classic menu, the advanced menu has search ability, which I feel is more convenient.

But the advanced menu will pop out whenever I press the windows key.
[image]

Is there a way to disable the windows key or not letting the menu pop out?

I tried the setting in this [post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1039142/how-can-i-disable-super-key-in-ubuntu-mate-18-04)

```
gsettings set org.mate.mate-menu hot-key ''
gsettings set com.solus-project.brisk-menu hot-key ''
```

But it does not work.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to do right mouse click on Menu, then select Preferences, click on the button at the right of Keyboard shortcut and hit <kbd>Backspace</kbd> to disable it.

Note what is interesting - the above GUI way triggers the same `/org/mate/mate-menu/hot-key` key, so you can use `dconf write /org/mate/mate-menu/hot-key "''"`. It will react on first <kbd>Super</kbd> hit, but will not react on next hits.