# How to use <super>+w/a/s/d as shortcuts?

Tags: shortcuts

I want to set <kbd>super</kbd>+ w/a/s/d to move workspaces. However <kbd>super</kbd>+s and <kbd>super</kbd>+w do not work.

First I had to disable`<super>` on [How do I disable the Super key?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/105558/how-do-i-disable-the-super-key)

Comment: Provide information about your current system and version. It all will depends on the window manager/desktop environment you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use compiz CCSM

```
sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager && ccsm
```

### "`<super>+w`"

CCSM>Window management>Scale>bindings --> disable `<super>+w`;

### `<super>+s`

CCSM>Desktop>Expo>Bindings --> disable `<super>+s`;