# Disable super + s on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: shortcut-keys, compiz, wayland

How to disable <kbd>super</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd> shortcut on Ubuntu 20.04. I have tried the compiz manager and then going to expo and then disabling expo key. But it won't work. I want to bind this shortcut for some other app.

If it makes any difference, I use Wayland and not X11.

I have tried the following solutions
[How to use <super>+w/a/s/d as shortcuts?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1073230/how-to-use-superw-a-s-d-as-shortcuts)
[Disable super + s in ubuntu 13.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/323982/disable-super-s-in-ubuntu-13-04)

Comment: Do you want super+S to do nothing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Go to Settings → *Keyboard shortcuts*.
2. Go to *System* shortcuts section.
3. Click on the shortcut with name *Show the overview* and key combination <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>.
4. Instead of adding anyother key binding to it just press <kbd>Backspace</kbd> and click on *Set*.

That's it, shortcut is disabled!!

Hope this helps :))