# How to unset Overlay (Super) key on my DE in order to proceed with Kinto in Lubuntu?

Tags: keyboard, lubuntu, keyboard-layout, macosx

Note that solution with gsettings recommended here does not seem to apply in Lubuntu: [How do I disable the Super key?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/105558/how-do-i-disable-the-super-key)

Kinto https://github.com/rbreaves/kinto is asking me to press the Super-Key but it will not be triggered in the app as it will open the applications in the taskbar

Therefore the solution is not to completely disable the Super Key as this is meant to be used and also need to be recorded by Kinto. Only need to disable its global effect

More specifically we are stuck in the Kinto setup screen where you have the prompt:

```
Identifying your Keyboard...

Press the 2nd key Left of the spacebar.

if stuck here then unset Overlay (Super) key on your DE
```

Obviously the 2nd key left to my keyboard is the Super-Key (aka Windows-Key)

Any ideas how to do so ?

Comment: you would do it in the shortcuts manager for lubuntu

Comment: try runing this `lxqt-config-globalkeyshortcuts` to configure them

Comment: @Inee it seems that this is the solution

Comment: @Inee, please write your comment as an answer, given OPs last comment.