# How to disable keyboard shortcut overlay that appears on super key hold in gnome desktop?

Tags: shortcut-keys, gnome-shell

I want to disable the keyboard shortcut overlay that appears on holding Super key in gnome desktop. How do I disable this?

I'm using Ubuntu Gnome 17.04.

I've searched and found the suggested solution([How can I disable the Windows key from opening the Activities overview?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/93746/how-can-i-disable-the-windows-key-from-opening-the-activities-overview)) not work for me. The suggested solution was to set:

`gsettings set org.gnome.mutter overlay-key 'Alt_R'`
but this didn't work :( How does one disable it?

Comment: Have you checked the other answer: https://askubuntu.com/a/979112/26246 with following command: `gsettings set org.gnome.mutter overlay-key ""`