# How to disable the Super Key? (18.04+)

Tags: shortcut-keys, gnome-shell, window-management

I want to disable the <kbd>Super</kbd> key, when I press <kbd>Super</kbd> nothing should happen.

I want to retain other shortcuts such as <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd> though.

How can I do that?

*[(Same question from 2012, none of the solutions work in 18.04, accepted answer included)](https://askubuntu.com/q/105558/4066)*
*[(Same question from 2012, but the accepted answer does not work)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/93746/how-can-i-disable-the-windows-key-from-opening-the-activities-overview)*

Comment: I'm assuming that you're actually using GNOME Shell, not Unity, otherwise the Unity answers would have worked.

Comment: @muru: The accepted answer at that URL does not work on 18.04, plus the UI is totally different now so the instructions are impossible to follow.

Comment: So? It has two more answers, both far more new.

Comment: @muru I remember a meta saying that if the accepted answer is outdated and false, then asking the same question for a new release is OK. I will try to find that meta page.

Comment: Sure, go ahead. But remember what accepting is: it's only an indication that the answer helped *OP*. It doesn't say anything about validity of the other answers, especially when the OP is no longer active. That the accepted answer may no longer work is no reason to ignore other answers. That is also why we're allowed to post answers long after an answer has been updated.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I used on ubuntu 18.04

```
gsettings set org.gnome.mutter overlay-key 'Alt_R'
```

to deactivate super, and it retain shortcuts too.

Comment: Great, worked immediately. It survives reboot.