# how to Disable windows key(left+right) on ubuntu23.10?

Tags: command-line, keyboard, shortcut-keys, gnome-terminal, keycodes

While working with ubuntu 23.10, I want to disable the functioning of the <kbd>Windows</kbd> key from the command or program. How can I achieve it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://askubuntu.com/q/93746/730458

Comment: @ChuckLiu yes, but when I am trying to execute it with c code it is not working. while other commands work perfectly.

Comment: in C , I am using system("gsettings set org.gnome.mutter overlay-key ' ' ");

Comment: Your comment has a space inside `' '`, whereas one of the linked question's answers does not and has `""`

Comment: I did it without space. But still not working.

Comment: What do you get if you type `gsettings get org.gnome.mutter overlay-key` in bash?

Comment: ' '
I got this after the executing the command (gsettings get org.gnome.mutter overlay-key)

Comment: Then the C and bash code is fine. Do you have anything else in Settings > Keyboard > Keyboard shortcuts > View... set to that Windows key? You can also try setting the overlay-key to something else you don't need like 'Menu'

Comment: As I tried every single possibilities to do it with code. And I noticed that If I run it as script and try to run in terminal without using sudo i.e;  ./script.sh it works. But If I try to run it with sudo i.e; sudo ./script.sh it does not works. what is the logic for it? anyone please.  command that I used in my script file is :-

gsettings set org.gnome.mutter overlay-key ''

Comment: When you run it as root, it writes to `/root/.config/dconf/user`. When you run it without sudo, it writes to `/home/username/.config/dconf/user`. These are two different files. You might want `system("su username -c \"gsettings set org.gnome.mutter overlay-key '' \"");`